# Ruby Grape POSTGRESQL stored procedure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-grape, grape-api

Trying to execute a POSTGRESQL stored procedure/function in Ruby Grape API Package. I have the function getactivesites() in my server which returns the site name.

server code:

```
BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY SELECT "SITE_ID",
            "SITE_NAME"
        FROM public.sites WHERE "ACTIVE_FLAG" = true
        ORDER BY "SITE_NAME" ASC ;
    END;
```

ruby code:

```
resource :getsites do

desc “Get Active Sites“
get do
  results =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("execute getactivesites")
  return results
end
```

The error I get when I run it is “PG::InvalidSqlStatementName: ERROR: prepared statement "getactivesites" does not exist : execute getactivesites”

Comment: Does the `getactivesites` procedure work if you run it directly in the postgres console?

Comment: For example, is the procedure defined in your development database but not your test database? (If you have multiple databases?...)

Comment: Yes, getactivesites runs when I run in my postgres db. I have it in my development database and run my ruby on rails project on that same database.

Comment: ...But is that line failing when you run a *test*? Double check which database `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` is connecting to, when that line executes, in whatever context you are seeing the failure.

Comment: I think you don't need execute inside the parenthesis ```results =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("execute getactivesites")```. Just type ```results =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("getactivesites")``` and try again, and let me know if it worked.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard tried running by removing the execute get the error "PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "getactivesites" LINE 1: getactivesites ^ : getactivesites"

Comment: @TomLord I believe it is running in development, when I run any grape calls in that same file they return the information from the development db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `select` instead of `execute`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select getactivesites()")
```

Here is from my real proj:

```
Db.execute( 'select my_sp_name( ? )', my_sp_param )
```

where Db is sugar like:

```
# -*- frozen-string-literal: true -*-
# Syntax sugar module
module Db
  extend self

  delegate :transaction, to: ApplicationRecord

  def sanitize( *args )
    ApplicationRecord.send( :sanitize_sql, args )
  end

  def execute( *args )
    ApplicationRecord.connection.execute( sanitize( *args ) )
  end

end
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: @Swish2121 Can you mark the answer as correct? Thanks

Comment: To run that first piece of code need to add () to have: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select getactivesites()")

Comment: @Swish2121 Ok, fixed the example. All SP in my proj. have params, so I couldn't test SP call without ones.